# What is the recommended method for securing a Crate.io installation

Tags: iptables, docker

I have installed an instance of Crate.io via docker on a CentOS 6.6 machine.

By default Crate.io runs on port 4200 and is open to the world.

I would like to secure this, so only the localhost can connect to the Crate service.

I have tried the following commands to accomplish this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4200 -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 4200 -j DROP
service iptables save
```

However, the service is still accessible on port 4200

I also noticed the following line in my iptables:

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.17.0.2          tcp dpt:4200
```

That rule has to do with the docker container, so I'm not sure how to proceed here.

Does anyone have a recommended procedure for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running services via Docker, then changes to your `INPUT` chain will not have any effect.  The iptables `INPUT` chain is for traffic that is destined *for your host*.  A docker container has it's own IP address, so when your *host* receives a packet on one of the exposed ports, it is *forwarded* to the container.  This means that rules in your `FORWARD` chain are relevant.

Docker adds forwarding rules when you expose ports with `-p` or `-P`.  You could block access by inserting additional rules in the `FORWARD` chain earlier than the docker rules, but that gets tricky (because you would need to manually update the rules every time you re-deployed the container).

If you only want to access the service from your local host, your best bet is to simply not expose any ports with `-p` or `-P`. You will still be able to access the containerized service using the IP address of the container (in your example, 172.17.0.2).